# Add Dynamic Directory to RotatingServerAdvice Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to use the RotatingServerAdvice to poll new files from multiple resource. I have a new requirement that for every new client, a new directory is created in the sftp server and I want to add that directory to the poll as well. So I will be using int-sftp:outbound-gateway to query all directories and check whether a new directory is created then add the new directory to the key directories. Is it possible that way? Thank you.

```
@Bean
public RotatingServerAdvice advice() {
  List<RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory> keyDirectories = new ArrayList<>();
  keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory("one", "foo"));
  keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory("one", "bar"));
  keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory("two", "baz"));
  keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory("two", "qux"));
  keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory("three", "fiz"));
  keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory("three", "buz"));
  return new RotatingServerAdvice(delegatingSf(), keyDirectories);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with the default `StandardRotationPolicy`; you need to provide a custom `RotationPolicy`.

```java
/**
 * Construct an instance that rotates according to the supplied
 * {@link RotationPolicy}.
 * @param rotationPolicy the policy.
 */
public RotatingServerAdvice(RotationPolicy rotationPolicy) {
    Assert.notNull(rotationPolicy, "'rotationPolicy' cannot be null");
    this.rotationPolicy = rotationPolicy;
}
```

You can probably start with the `StandardRotationPolicy` as a model.